# In the context of machine learning deep learning, what does a "log space" mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logarithms, machine-learning

ch06 of "[deeplearningbook](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html)" says

> This approach to predicting the probabilities in `log space` is natural
>   to use with maximum likelihood learning.

"log space" also appears a lot of times in math.stackexchange.com.

so, what is "log space", In the context of machine learning deep learning?

does "log space" mean put a log on any function?

I googled it and the most likely result linked to [L (complexity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_(complexity)) without any explanation about Logarithmic space.

Comment: Yes, "predicting the probabilities in log space" is another way of saying "predicting the log of the probabilities". The reason for talking about "log space" is to suggest the perspective that we are still predicting the probabilities, only transformed into a different space where they are easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please mv your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The $\log$ probabilities are just summed to find the $\log$ probability of the intersection of independent events, that's why they appear everywhere